# GWT, How to use js libraries like jqplot in gwt

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I am starting to learn GWT. For now I have been using Spring, playframework, where I have been using JavaScript libraries. For example, I wrote my own JS library to print trees.

Now I wonder, in case of lack some functionality in gwt widgets, can I import/ convert/ adopt my JS library to work inside in gwt library?

I found some information about it, but none of them was new, so I am afraid that they will be outdated.

Base widgets aren't plenty. Everybody discouraged me from using smartgwt, and gwt ext isn't open sourced.

Please give me some thoughts, base on your experience.

Comment: Well, you could try [GwtQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) and use that to write more "native" JavaScript. A better question is why bother with GWT at all? =p

Comment: I hate hard coded Strings. I prefer type safe for my application. Gwt is only framework that can deliver it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

Of course, it is not as easy as using js libraries directly in js code, but is very flexible. After you integrate the desired API parts from the underlying js library, you can invoke it with GWT (Java), thus utilizing the best from both worlds.